# Why does my display freezes when parsing double to a String

Tags: c#, events, tostring

Hey I always want to compare the first two elements in my list (double) so that is my code:

```
            String allMarks = "";
            String toString1 = "";
            String toString2 = "";

            if (eventcounter.Count > 1)
            {
                allMarks = allMarks + eventcounter[0];

                for (int i = 0; i < eventcounter.Count; i++)
                {
                    toString1 = eventcounter[i].ToString();

                    for (int j = 1; j <= eventcounter.Count; i++)
                    {
                        toString2 = eventcounter[j].ToString();

                        if (toString1 != toString2)//(eventcounter[i] != eventcounter[j])
                        {
                            allMarks = allMarks + eventcounter[j];
                            Console.WriteLine(allMarks);

                        }
                    }
                }

            }
```

I dont really get why my Eventcounter will not be displayed on my app.

04-03 19:14:09.326 D/InputTransport(29861): Input channel constructed: fd=71
04-03 19:14:09.330 V/InputMethodManager(29861): Starting input: tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@1c5db21 nm : accelerometer2.accelerometer2 ic=null
04-03 19:14:09.658 I/art     (29861): Starting a blocking GC Explicit
04-03 19:14:09.675 I/art     (29861): Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 18697(999KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 39% free, 9MB/15MB, paused 123us total 17.306ms
04-03 19:14:09.676 D/Mono    (29861): GC_TAR_BRIDGE bridges 3 objects 4 opaque 1 colors 3 colors-bridged 3 colors-visible 3 xref 0 cache-hit 0 cache-semihit 0 cache-miss 0 setup 0.02ms tarjan 0.00ms scc-setup 0.02ms gather-xref 0.00ms xref-setup 0.01ms cleanup 0.03ms
04-03 19:14:09.676 D/Mono    (29861): GC_BRIDGE: Complete, was running for 17.88ms
04-03 19:14:09.676 D/Mono    (29861): GC_MINOR: (Nursery full) time 1.11ms, stw 1.46ms promoted 73K major size: 784K in use: 122K los size: 0K in use: 0K
04-03 19:14:09.959 D/Mono    (29861): GC_TAR_BRIDGE bridges 0 objects 0 opaque 0 colors 0 colors-bridged 0 colors-visible 3 xref 0 cache-hit 0 cache-semihit 0 cache-miss 0 setup 0.02ms tarjan 0.00ms scc-setup 0.02ms gather-xref 0.00ms xref-setup 0.01ms cleanup 0.00ms
04-03 19:14:09.959 D/Mono    (29861): GC_BRIDGE: Complete, was running for 0.07ms

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like an infinite loop because your second for loop is incrementing `i` instead of `j`.